# How can I embed a snippet before the closing </body> tag in Docusaurus?

Tags: docusaurus

I want to install this snippet immediately before the `</body>` tag on my Docusaurus site.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  window._mfq = window._mfq || [];
  (function() {
    var mf = document.createElement("script");
    mf.type = "text/javascript"; mf.defer = true;
    mf.src = "//cdn.mouseflow.com/projects/95f.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(mf);
  })();
</script>
```

I see the concept of `postBodyTags` at https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/docusaurus-config#ssrTemplate, but it's undocumented.

Should I just pretend that I didn't notice the concept of `postBodyTags` and just edit the `ssrTemplate` HTML string to include my snippet?